# Thymeleaf - Generate an image url with dynamic url

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Im trying to visualize some information about a blog post described by this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "blog_posts")
public class BlogPost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "thumbnail_path")
    private String thumbnailPath;

    @Column(name = "body")
    private String body;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private User author;

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private Date date = new Date();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getThumbnailPath() {
        return thumbnailPath;
    }

    public void setThumbnailPath(String thumbnailPath) {
        this.thumbnailPath = thumbnailPath;
    }
}
```

With a Thymeleaf generated html like this:

```
 <div class="text-center mt-3 rounded bg-white p-2" th:each="blog_post: ${blog_posts}">
                    <div class="blog_video position-relative">
                        <div class="img_blog">
                            <img th:src="@{~/images/blog/{blog_post.id}/{blog_post.thumbnailPath}}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block">
                        </div>
                        <!-- <a href="http://vimeo.com/99025203" class="blog_play"><i class="mdi mdi-play"></i></a>  -->
                    </div>
```

The problem arises when I'm trying to generate a dynamic url for the img tag. How do i inject variables like **{blog_post.id}** inside this th:src attribute dynamically? I cannot find the solution so Im hoping for a helping hand here.

**~EDIT~**: Turned out the following code does the trick but it still looks pretty messy. Anyone know a better way than this:

```
 <img th:src="@{/images/blog/{id}/{thumbnail}(id=${blog_post.id}, thumbnail=${blog_post.thumbnailPath})}" alt="No image preview" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block">
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way:

```
<img th:src="@{'/images/blog/' +${blog_post.id} +'/' +${blog_post.thumbnailPath}}"
```

But I think your method look cleaner :)